# How to change colour of circular lines in polar chart depending on value of theta (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the directivity patterns of microphones. I want to have a different color depending on the value of theta. So for all values of `theta > 90 degrees & theta < 270 degrees` I want the line color to be red. For all other values, I want the color to be blue.

I want something that does something like the below

```py
theta = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.01)
r = abs(0.0 + 1*np.cos(theta))


fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
line, = ax.plot(theta,r)

for t in theta:
    if t > np.pi/2 and t < 3*np.pi/2:
        line.set_color('red')  
    else:
        line.set_color('blue')
```

This obviously doesn't work as every call to `line.set_color()` changes the color of the whole line, but is there anyway I could change the color of the specific `theta,r` value being plotted at each point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a masked array from `numpy` (look [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#)).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

theta = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 0.01)
r = abs(0.0 + 1 * np.cos(theta))

limit_inferior = np.pi / 2
limit_superior = 3 * np.pi / 2

# Pay attention to the conditionals
theta_01 = np.ma.masked_where((theta > limit_inferior) & (theta < limit_superior), theta)
theta_02 = np.ma.masked_where((theta <= limit_inferior) | (theta >= limit_superior), theta)

# Print these to see the values 
# print(theta_01)
# print(theta_02)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})

ax.plot(theta_02, r, c='red')
ax.plot(theta_01, r, c='blue')
fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Probably the part that is not easy to grasp immediately is the code for `theta_01` and `theta_02`. For `theta_01`, I am masking values that are greater than 90° **and** smaller than 270°; for `theta_02`, I am masking values that are smaller than 90° **or** greater than 270°. Fortunately, the order of plotting doesn't matter in this case (sometimes it matters).